# Export Oracle table into CSV uisng SQL/PlSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is there way to export Oracle table into CSV file ? I do not want to do it through Java but directly using any SQL/PLSQL command.

My table has few columns of type int, date, varchar. Column count is low say 5. But row count can be large 50 thousand+.

**EDIT**

I could think of below solution

```
spool on;
spool c:/7Jun.txt;
select ID||','||DESCRIPTION||','||CATEGORY from kaushik where id<=10;
spool out;
spool off;
```

This creates a file like

```
select ID||','||DESCRIPTION||','||CATEGORY from NLC where id<=10 ID||','||DESCRIPTION||','||CATEGORY                                                  
1,das
2,2342
3,434
4,4erwerw       5,trtsds 
5 rows selected
```

Comment: Have you tried searching? There are many good resources about this

Comment: Yes. Many options are using some tools or java programs. I did not find any SQL/PLSQL command. If you know any please give link.

Comment: [This](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:88212348059) may be a good starting point

Comment: or [this](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/generating-csv-files)